# Is there a function that gives you index of last char substring in string?

Tags: c++, string, function

The find() function gives you index of first char of substring in string, I need last char.

I tried to get length of substring and sum it to first index but it is going out of bound.

```
  // if( str2.substr(last char index, str2.find(part3)))


        int sizeOfPart2 = part2.length();
    int sizeOfPart3 = part3.length();
    if(sizeOfPart2 == 1){
        sizeOfPart2 = 0;
    }
    else if(sizeOfPart3 == 1){
        sizeOfPart3 = 0;
    }
   cout<<str2.substr(str2[str2.find(part2) + sizeOfPart2], 
   str2.find(part3));
```

Comment: Use std::string, and std::string's find method. (Don't use "C" style char[]). And are you sure you really want the index? Or is that just HOW you would get to the last character in the string. If you only need the last character use std::string's back method

Comment: Try rfind maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind

Comment: OP : Next time show the code you are using so we can give a better answer.

Comment: Yes i'm sure i need the index, cause i'm gonna substring() it next

Comment: Sorry, i meant sum, i'm not native speaker

Comment: Please give a short piece of code that someone can copy-compile-run and see the "going out of bound". Your partial `if` statement does not demonstrate this.

Comment: @EduardAtoyan *"Sorry, i meant sum,"* -- probably meant "add", but at least you've got the right operation implied now. ;) (Sorry, we can't assume something like your previous "multiply" was just a mis-translation or mis-type.)

Comment: @EduardAtoyan You should add some example inputs and your **expected output**. The question is unclear.

Comment: @JaMiT Here you go.

Comment: @JasonLiam i cant paste the whole code, there is string that was splited into 3 parts  by + -  =

Comment: Getting better. You can strip everything but the `cout` line, I think, since that does not appear to be needed to reproduce the issue. More importantly, please add data. As in: `std::string str2 = "what goes here?"; std::string part2 = "what?"; std::string part3 = "something";` (Of course, change the values as needed to reproduce. Keep the data simple, though, please.) And make it easier to reproduce. Start with `int main() {` and end with `}` so that it can be compiled as-is.

Comment: str = "x^2+x+1";
 string str2 = str;
for (auto& spliter : str) {
   if (spliter == '+' || spliter == '-' || spliter == '=') {
    spliter = ' ';
   }
  }

  istringstream strm(str);
  string part;
  while (strm >> part) {
   parts.push_back(part);
  }

Comment: Looks like this might be a [mre]: `#include <string> int main() { std::string st2 = "x^2+x+1";  std::string part2 = "x^2"; std::string part3 = "x"; unsigned sizeOfPart2 = part2.length(); std::cout<<str2.substr(str2[str2.find(part2) + sizeOfPart2], str2.find(part3)); }` -- no fancy prep work. Determine what the values of your variables should be, and simply set them to those values. This is just an **example**, so focused is good. *If this is adequate to demonstrate the issue, please update your question.*

Comment: [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
const std::string path = "repeatedstrieang";
std::string mysubstr = "ea";
auto firstCharPos = path.find("ea");
if(firstCharPos!=std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << firstCharPos + mysubstr.size() -1; //-1 because indexing starts from `0`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do something like the below helper function I made. It returns the index of the last character of the substring.

Stepwise details:

1. Find the substring: this gives the index of the first char of the substring.
2. If the index is out of bound, return -1 to denote that the substring cannot be found.
3. Else if the index is valid, add it to the length of the substring - 1. This is done to get the index of the actual character.

```cpp
int findLastCharSubstring(std::string text, std::string substring){
    int index = text.find(substring);
    if(index != std::string::npos) // If in bound, return correct index
        return index + substring.length() - 1;
    else // If out of bound return -1, i.e. not found
        return -1;
}
```